# Max/Min Problems with an inequality constraint

Tags: complex-analysis

The [Lagrange Multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) Method is usually used to deal with the maximizing or minimizing problem subject to a constraint which is usually an equality. Consider the following problem:

> $$f(z)=|z^2-iz|,\quad z\in{\mathbb C}$$
>    where $$|z|\leq 2$$
>   What is the maximum of $f(z)$?

It seems that the Lagrange Multiplier can not be used here. What I think is that one may let $z=x+iy$, find the critical point, and use the second-derivative test.

- Is there a **quick** way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|z|\le2$ implies $f(z)\le|z^2|+|iz|=|z|^2+|z|\le2^2+2=6$. Since $f(-2i)=6$, there's your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the Maximum Modulus Principle and conclude that the maximum is on $\vert z\vert = 2$, then apply the Lagrange Multiplier Method. ;)

Comment: Hmm, this gives a general method to solve this kinds of problems.